# How can I fetch the source code from a website that is blocking the requests when we use python bs4, selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to scrape the data present in this website "https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105". I tried using beautiful soup and selenium,

The first approach:

```
import requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

This was not giving the output i was expecting, the fetched page contains something like this "Sorry, something about your browser or browsing activity made us think you were a robot."

The second approach:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
url="https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105"
PATH = r"C:\Users\Vinay Edula\Desktop\xxxxxxxx\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)
```

This approach works fine for one or two pages in that site but then after the problem is this website is blocking the requests.

Approach 3:

```
import webbrowser
url="https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105"
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'


for i in range(10):
    url="https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105&cursor="+str(i*10)+"&limit=10"
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
    time.sleep(10)
```

This code working fine, it was opening the site in chrome without any error or blockibg but i dont know how to fetch the source code.

When the python code tries to fetch the code or by accessing from the guest browser as selenium did i am getting error. When I manually opens this webpage or using webbrowser module in python I can able to see the contents. So how can i solve this problem , my final aim is to fetch the contents present from this paginated site https://www.findhelp.org/care/support-network--san-francisco-ca?postal=94105? .

Any solution for this problem will be will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried sleeping for 10 seconds (just as you do in the third approach), but when using Selenium (the second approach)? High chances the server blocks you, because you issue the requests too fast. With Selenium, you can access the page's source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page_source property of Selenium as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://example.com")
```